# Eigenspace of convex combination of two idempotent matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, idempotents

Let $H_1,H_2\in\mathbb{Q}^{n\times n}$ be idempotent and symmetric matrices. For any $0<\mu<\frac{1}{2}$, consider the matrix

$$H_\mu:=\mu H_1+(1-\mu)H_2.$$

I'm looking for a description of $\text{Eig}(H_\mu,\mu)$.

Clearly, $\text{img}(H_1)\cap\ker(H_2)\subseteq\text{Eig}(H_\mu,\mu)$, but under which conditions do we have equality? Is there a description of the "missing piece"

$$\text{Eig}(H_\mu,\mu)/\text{img}(H_1)\cap\ker(H_2)?$$

Comment: I suppose these are non commuting matrices; otherwise the answer would be too easy by simultaneously diagonalising the matrices.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Yes, in general they do not commute.

Comment: In the meantime, this question has been answered on [mathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/233245/eigenspace-of-convex-combination-of-two-idempotent-matrices)